# Calling a (working)REST WebService from Java freezes with no response

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jakarta-ee, junit

For this question I've only provided the bare minimum of code, since providing everything related to this problem would be to much. If you have an idea and want to see a specific implementation, of course I will provide that afterwards.

Since this is probably a general problem and not an error in the code, I suppose it's enough anyway.

I wrote a JUnit systemtest, to test some of my web services. If I test 1 service per method (for example "writeTest"), it works. With every test.
They work if I call them using SOAP UI as well.

Unfortunately, since I'm trying to write, read and delete objects to my db, I need to write an object before I can read it. And here is the problem. While writing works, reading it results in a freeze.

- No exception
- No logs
- No JUnit error
- No timeout
- No response
- By remote debugging I've confirmed, my service is not even called.

If I change the order, reading works and writing results in a frozen state. If I call writing or reading twice it still works! BUT the moment I put **2** **different** **service** calls in **1 method**, I get this problem.

After spending 2 days on this, I found a workaround by closing the client connection and opening a new one. Unfortunately this is not very clean.

Any suggestions on how to solve this matter are appretiated. Since the client contains self written code, this might be a programming issue afterall, but let's assume it's not, since it's used in a couple of other classes with no problem at all (still, please feel free to ask for more code if you have a guess, what the problem might be).

Thank you.

```
    @Test
    public void myTests() {

        //Create simple object first
        try {
            client.getMyWebService().writeTest(repo, object, prop);
        } catch (final WebApplicationException | ParseException e) {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }  

        resetClient();

        //Read the object
        Properties result= new DataExtensionObjectParam();
        try {       
            result = client.getMyWebService().readTest(repo, object);//Freeze           
        } catch (final WebApplicationException | ParseException e) {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
    }


    private void resetClient() {

      client.closeClient();
      try {
          client = getStandardClient();
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      } 
    }
```

Comment: Does the initial write really work?  Can you see the data from an external tool?  In other words, was the connection committed and/or closed (to be released back to a connection pool)?  Step through the code to see which line of code is hanging.

Comment: result = client.getMyWebService().readTest(repo, object);//Freeze  This one is hanging... "client.getMyWebService()" works, but once ".read..." is called it freezes forever. I've used remote debugging on my "read" web service. It is never called, so somewhere in between my call is "lost". Without a timeout, exception or anything else, though. Those services work, I can see that in my DB. If I would remove the "write", the "read" wouldn't freeze anymore. Keep in mind "resetClient()" is a workaround. The code as it is now works, but I don't want to close/open the connection everytime.